The requested REST API version of 7.0 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 6.1
I have a local on-premise TFS2020/DevOps (18.181.32404.7 - Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2) server with multiple project collections.
When I connect to any of the projects on one of the collections (using VS2022) and try to view work items I get the error...

The requested REST API version of 7.0 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 6.1.

However, if I connect to any of the projects in any of the other collections (on the same server) I get no errors and can see the work items correctly.
This has only occurred within the last few days and - to my knowledge - nothing has changed on either the server or my laptop (I am responsible for any changes to the server so I should know).
Other users can view the work items in the affected collection (again, using VS2022) without issue - it only appears to be affecting me. I can also view the work items without problem if I use the web interface (so I believe it is unlikely to be permissions) and I could view them from VS2022 a week or so ago.
I have today updated VS2022 to the latest version (17.10.5) in the hope that the update might reset "something", but the problem persists.
Any suggestions? I have found a couple of SO questions here and here but nothing that appears to be related to Visual Studio. I am also struggling to find anything that looks related elsewhere online.
TIA.
EDIT#1: I have just tried inspecting the request(s) from VS2022 to the TFS instance.
When requesting work items from a project in the collection that fails, VS2022 sends the following header as a part of the request...
Accept: application/json; api-version=7.0

However, when sending the work item request for a project in one of the other collections (that works), the header changes...
Accept: application/json; api-version=6.1-preview

This is kind of making me believe that this could be something configured at the client end after all - still not sure what though!
EDIT#2: When the failing request is sent (api-version=7.0), the server responds with HTTP/400 (Bad Request) and the body contains the following...
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The requested REST API version of 7.0 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 6.1.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssVersionOutOfRangeException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssVersionOutOfRangeException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Still believe it is client side though; just cannot see what is causing it to request that API version.

I have today raised this on the Microsoft Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-requested-REST-API-version-of-70-is/10716140

Based on the current situation, I am guessing that it's related to your client. You can try to reset Visual Studio Settings. Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings. If it doesn't work, uninstall your VS and re-install it.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer to wait before doing this as I have now reported it on Developer Community and may be asked for further feedback. At least I can still use the web interface for the moment.

I understand you. We can wait to see if the DevOps support has any other suggestion. At the same time, you can try to remove the old connections and re-add them back. Then check if there is the same issue or nor.
